# Where to put a shared library in JBoss AS 5?

Tags: java, jboss, jboss5.x, jboss-portal

I m new to Jboss, but I have multiple web applications each using spring-hibernate and other open source libraries and portlets, so basically now each war file includes those jar files. How do I move these jars to a common location so that I don't have to put these in each war file? I guess location is `server/default/lib`, but I'm not sure.

Also, how is it different to have those jars at `WEB-INF/lib`  vs. `JBOSS/server/default/lib`? Will I face any classloader issue?

Also I have static data stored in static fields like `Singleton`, will those be shared across all WAR files?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Classloading:**

You're right, put the `.jar`s to `JBOSS/server/<configuration>/lib`, or `JBOSS/lib`.

JBoss AS comes with bundled Hibernate libs which are tested with that AS version.

See `jboss-6.0.0-SNAPSHOT\server\default\conf\jboss-service.xml`:

```
<server>
  <!-- Load all jars from the JBOSS_HOME/server/<config>/lib directory and
       the shared JBOSS_HOME/common/lib directory. This can be restricted to
       specific jars by specifying them in the archives attribute.
       TODO: Move this configuration elsewhere
  -->
  <classpath codebase="${jboss.server.lib.url}" archives="*"/>
  <classpath codebase="${jboss.common.lib.url}" archives="*"/>
</server>
```

Also see:

- http://community.jboss.org/wiki/classloadingconfiguration
- http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JbossClassLoadingUseCases

**Difference between `WEB-INF/lib` and `JBOSS/server/default/lib`:**

Libs in `WEB/lib` come with your WAR and are only visible within that WAR.
If you have other module, e.g. EJB JAR, they will not be visible from it and you'll get `ClassNotFoundException` or (if you have the class in multiple places) `ClassCastException`.

Libs in `JBOSS-AS/server/<config>/lib` are visible for whole server, thus all deployed apps and their modules. However (IIRC) they don't have precedence, so if you bring that lib e.g. in a WAR, but not in EJB jar, you can end up using two different versions, which is undesirable (will likely lead to aforementioned `ClassCastException`).

Class loading behavior may be tweaked several ways, see e.g. [JBoss wiki](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ClassLoadingConfiguration).

**Static data:**

Don't rely on static fields in Java EE, that brings troubles. For instance,. the same class can be loaded by different classloaders, so there will be multiple instances of these static values.
If you want to share data amongst more WARs, use an external storage - a database, a file (with synchronization if you write to it), JBoss Cache, etc.

Comment: +1 i prefer a own dedicated directory for my own shared jar's this makes it easier to maintain

Answer (score 2):

http://www.mastertheboss.com/en/jboss-server/211-configuring-jboss-shared-libs.html

Answer (score 0):

JBOSS/server/default/lib works fine.

All the jars in that folder will be loaded into JBoss.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to %JBOSS_HOME%\server\default\conf directory
2. Open file jboss-service.xml
3. Under tag  you will find

Add a new classpath tag as below to include the sharedlib folder on your local machine

Note: Please make sure to include file protocol to code base