# How to split war files if the file size is large and deploy it in same context root 

Tags: jsp, jboss, war, contextroot

We are having a war file containing jsp fils which is about 40 MB. when we deploy this file its taking long time to deploy. so we want to split the files in different wars, If we split files the context root will differ. I need a solution to bring this jsp file usder same context-root. Kindly help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the majority of your WAR file size are libraries under `/WEB-INF/lib`. You can place most (if not all) JARs in JBoss directly, which will result in very small WAR. Take a look here: [Where to put a shared library in JBoss AS 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108975)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is possible. Take a look at a thread - [Multiple war files for a single webapp or context - coderanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/555880/Servlets/java/Multiple-war-files-single-webapp)

Comment: we are mostly lib files, so we removed it from war and deployed it in lib. thanks for your reply.