# Jboss 4.2.3 custom shared lib

Tags: deployment, jboss, shared-libraries, jboss-4.2.x

I am in the process of moving the shared libraries to some custom jboss lib folder.
Right now as I see, libs are placed under

> 1)Jboss/lib folder
>
> 2)Jboss/server/FM/lib
>
> 3)WebInf/Lib in the webapp's

Now I want to move some of the libs which are shared by the webapp's in shared lib but not under jboss/server/FM/lib as I want them to at separate folder something like below:

> jboss/server/FM/lib/custom.

I would still like libraries to loaded from Jboss/server/Fm/lib as well.
Is there any way to do in Jboss 4.2.3
I had a look at the similar questions on stackoverflow but I couldnt find any satisfactory answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add in `JBoss/server/TM/conf/jboss-service.xml` after line

```
   <classpath codebase="${jboss.server.lib.url:lib}" archives="*"/>
```

another line

```
   <classpath codebase="${jboss.server.lib.url:lib}/custom" archives="*"/>
```

and restart.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108975/where-to-put-a-shared-library-in-jboss-as-5

Comment: Thanks @Vadzim...It worked.I thought I have tried this solution yesterday which gave me failure...I suppose I had messed up something else as well..Started afresh in the morning after your response and glad that it worked :)