# JBoss: Load jars in lib's subfolders

Tags: java, jboss

Is there a way to make JBoss load .jar files that are placed within sub-folders of a specific lib folder?

We unfortunately can't use a dependency management tool such as Maven in our environment and packaging jars into folders would help for manual management.

Comment: Doesn't JBoss use any .jar file in the WEB-INF/lib directory?

Comment: @Nicholas It does, but we'd like to package shared jars and per-project jars using sub-folders.

Comment: Maybe try [Jboss 4.2.3 custom shared lib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161991/jboss-4-2-3-custom-shared-lib)

Comment: @Nicholas That would probably work, but I hoped for a dynamic recursive scanning... is there a way to implement a custom loader?

Comment: are you sure that jboss doesn't recursively look at the jars in the WEB-INF/lib folder?